# Jackson cannot deserialize single field class, although Creator exists

Tags: json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I have the following simple jUnit test:

```java
class MyTest {
 
   static class SingleField {
        int rank;
        SingleField(int rank) {
            this.rank = rank;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            if(!(o instanceof  SingleField)) {
                return  false;
            } else {
                return ((SingleField) o).rank == rank;
            }
        }
    }

   @Test
    public void testBasicJacksonParsing() throws JsonProcessingException {
        assertEquals(new SingleField(3), new ObjectMapper().readValue("{\"rank\" : 3}", SingleField.class));
    }
   
}
```

Unfortunately, when run, the test throws a `MismatchedInputException` with message:

```
Cannot construct instance of `com.drfirst.gear.user.context.util.AppUtilTest$SingleField` (although at least one Creator exists): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (String)"{"rank" : 3}"; line: 1, column: 2]
```

The accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032293/cannot-construct-instance-of-class-name-although-at-least-on-creator-exists/55032325) seems to imply that one needs an all-args constructor. I clearly have one. I have also tried the same unit test by making the constructor of `SingleField` `public`, and I have also changed `rank` to `String`, making sure I also update the `String` I am parsing from `"{\"rank\" : 3}"` to `"{\"rank\" : \"3\"}"`. Same `Exception` thrown.

Ideas on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed `public` setters for my fields.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not says that a public setter works.  But https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641620/make-jackson-deserialize-into-private-fields-without-setter-or-constructor says you can do it without if you write a custom deserializer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a Maven Kotlin project and solved it by added the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.2</version>
</dependency>
```